# How save a drawable-imageBitmap in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, bitmap

I have a screen that what it does is that the user can choose an avatar from those that appear on the screen to be their profile photo, then I have in the Profile Fragment a screen where I show the username and the profile photo, to I use currentUser.photoUrl for the profile photo but when I run the application it does not load the photo, nor does it save the photo in Firebase, I am using a method called "saveAvatar" that does this:

suspend fun saveAvatar(imageBitmap: Bitmap?) {
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

```
    if (user != null && imageBitmap != null) {
        val imageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("${user.email}/profile_picture")

        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val data = baos.toByteArray()

        // Sube la imagen a Firebase Storage
        imageRef.putBytes(data).await()

        // Obtiene la URL de descarga de la imagen cargada
        val downloadUrl = imageRef.downloadUrl.await().toString()

        // Actualiza la foto de perfil en el perfil del usuario
        val profileUpdates = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(downloadUrl))
            .build()

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    }

}
```

In the fragment to choose the avatar I have this:

```
    binding.imgProfile1.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile1.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)

    }


    binding.imgProfile2.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile2.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)

    }

    binding.imgProfile3.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile3.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)

    }

    binding.imgProfile4.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile4.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)

    }

    binding.imgProfile5.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile5.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)

    }

    binding.imgProfile6.setOnClickListener {
        selectedAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ricardobochini)
        binding.imgProfile6.setImageBitmap(selectedAvatar)
    }


    binding.selectImage.setOnClickListener {
        if (selectedAvatar != null) {
            viewModel.saveAvatar(selectedAvatar)
           
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_avatarProfileFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }

    }

    binding.skip.setOnClickListener {
       
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_avatarProfileFragment_to_homeFragment)
    }
```

And to show the photo in the profile I use this:

Glide.with(this).load(currentUser?.photoUrl).centerCrop().into(binding.avatarProfile)

I think I'm doing something wrong in saveAvatar but I don't know what, I've already tried several ways and it can't show the photo

Comment: Have you tried to add a try-catch block to those operations, to see if something went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Update a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser

val profileUpdates = userProfileChangeRequest {
    displayName = "Jane Q. User"
    photoUri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl)
}

user!!.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.")
        }
    }
```

[Get a user's provider-specific profile information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information)

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
user?.let {
    for (profile in it.providerData) {
        // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
        val providerId = profile.providerId

        // UID specific to the provider
        val uid = profile.uid

        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        val name = profile.displayName
        val email = profile.email
        val photoUrl = profile.photoUrl
    }
}
```

[Get a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
user?.let {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    val name = it.displayName
    val email = it.email
    val photoUrl = it.photoUrl

    // Check if user's email is verified
    val emailVerified = it.isEmailVerified

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
    val uid = it.uid
}
```